# How can I use ALL system registered themes/styles in my Delphi App?

Tags: delphi, themes

With `Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager.StyleNames`, I have access to just the style names enabled in the project options (Application/Appearance).

How can I list all of the style names registered in the system, and make it active in Delphi 11?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fill a `TComboBox` with the available styles:

```
procedure FillComboboxWithStyles;
var
  stylename: string;
begin
  for stylename in TStyleManager.StyleNames do
    CBVclStyles.Items.Add(stylename);
end;
```

To activate a certain style you fill `TStyleManager.SetStyle(const Name: string)` with the stylename. For example the selected one from the `TComboBox`.

```
if (CBVclStyles.ItemIndex >= 0) then
  TStyleManager.SetStyle(CBVclStyles.Items[CBVclStyles.ItemIndex])
else
  ;// handle a non-selected style
```

Don't forget `Vcl.Themes` in your `uses`.

Comment: I did the same, but TStyleManager.StyleNames does not contain ALL style names, just the ones checked in the project options (Application/Appearance). I need a list like in the project options. Let the user select from the list of all styles, not from the filtered style list.

Comment: The user can only select from the styles that are linked into the exe. There is no way to access something from your machine when the application is executed at the users machine. Check all styles in the project options and they will be in the list.

Comment: @UweRaabe So it is a build time linked resource and not an environmental one. thx for your answer.

Comment: @UweRaabe But how the list in the project options created? there should be something API call to enumerate over the system styles. Or it is just the list of styles enabled/linked when the bds.exe compiled?

Comment: @SOLIDDevelopper the **IDE** knows all of the available styles that are *installed* and accessible to it.  It lets you choose which styles you want to link into your EXE.  When you then run your EXE, it only knows about the styles which it was compiled with.

Comment: @RemyLebeau But how does the IDE collect the styles? I want to do the same!

Comment: @SOLIDDevelopper You CAN'T do the same as the IDE. Styles are available to the IDE differently than they are available to your app. Any *unselected* styles in the IDE *will not exist* inside of your app. That is why UweRaabe said that you will have to select ALL of the styles in the project settings, so that they are ALL available to your app. What part of that is unclear to you?

Comment: @RemyLebeau What not clear about that : today win theme style list is not the same the one in the future.

Comment: @SOLIDDevelopper if new styles are released in the future, you will have to recompile your app to include them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau "You CAN'T do the same as the IDE. Styles are available to the IDE differently than they are available to your app." I don't think so. If I can collect the system available style name list, I can load it with TStyleManager.LoadXXX methods (if the StyleName list ot the manager does not contain the selected name)

Answer (score 0):

You can include the style files (*.vsf from C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Redist\styles\vcl with 22.0 marking your RAD Studio version) along with (externally from) your .EXE and then iterate over them when you fill your ComboBox. Then manually load the style from the file with TStyleManager.LoadFromFile when selected.

This will also allow your user to add his own style files to the setup.

This, I believe, is what the IDE does (except that it reads the list directly from the folder, since there's no "installation" of a style other than making the file available in a recognized location).

Comment: So this files are not make part of the win but the VCL? There is not system folder for them like for the fonts?

Comment: @SOLIDDevelopper: That's right. They are a VCL-specific style system, not a Windows one (and there are other style files that are compatible with FMX applications - these are not compatible with VCL applications).